# Rest api call from jquery ajax gives error 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to make a simple jquery ajax call to API

My code:

```
     jQuery.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://example.com/api/v1/testapi",
         headers: { "Authorization": "Basic Ylc5aWXXXXXXlk1ucWx5ZnA=" },
         success: function (data, status) {
             // do something
         },

         error: function (status) {
             // error handler
         }
});
```

Request headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/testapi HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 10:43:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
access-control-allow-headers: origin, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-credentials: 1
X-Debug-Token: 0346f5
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

Api working with postman but gives error 403 Forbidden when I called it from JQuery ajax

Answer (score 0):

paste that code above your main page of web services.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) 
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') 
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

Comment: web service url is live or in local? if it is live can you provide me?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests must be within [same domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). 
I tried the same from Firefox and got the error message as its a cross-domain AJAX call.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading 
the remote resource at http://example.com/api/v1/testapi.
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
```

Also it looks like you are setting the Authorization headers via JS. It would be safer to make a call to your server which in turn makes the API call by setting the Authorization headers so that it is not exposed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `X-RequestDigest` is expired or invalid so you need to call below method before REST call

```
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
```

Ref : http://sharepointsanjay.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-refresh-request-digest-token.html